# Puzzle based on Raven's Progressive Matrices/Abstract Reasoning

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

I created this puzzle and can assure everyone that this has an objective and definitive answer and is actually simple once you know exactly how the sequence works.

[image: a 3x3 grid in which the bottom right cell contains a question mark, while the 8 other cells contain various shapes made up of line segments]

Comment: I see that there's been some back-and-forth editing and from the edit-comments it seems that there is some hard feeling about some of the proposed changes. So, a few words from a moderator with no dog in the fight: 1. I'm like 99% sure that the replacement of "puzzle" with "lucky" in one edit was simply an autocorrect error, not any sort of sign of disrespect. 2. This isn't the place to re-litigate arguments you've had with moderators in other places who (I agree wrongly) didn't like your puzzle. Let it speak for itself. [... continues]

Comment: 3. Before the puzzle was solved, I'd have been entirely on board with offering some assurance that the puzzle has a definite solution, given that people elsewhere for some reason assumed it didn't; and with providing a bit of context to explain _why_ you were offering that assurance. But now it's been solved, anyone who doubts that there's a good solution can look at the accepted answer and judge for themselves. I don't think there's any need now even for the brief "this has an objective and definitive answer" [... continues]

Comment: ... note that currently stands at the beginning of the puzzle. Again, the puzzle and solution can speak for themselves. (It seems like a perfectly good puzzle to me, though I confess I'm not a fan of the whole broad class of puzzles that it belongs to.) The fact that it's on a positive score indicates that the denizens of PSE also generally don't think it's bad. (And I'll bet that more of the downvotes are for the complaining about another forum than for the puzzle itself.)

Comment: To add to Gareth's comments, I advise that the dispute shouldn't be continued in the About section on your profile page - it's not a good look, and it's pretty unfair to insult others on a page where nobody can counter-reply... (PS I imagine some downvotes may relate to the use of the symbol at the end of the middle row, to which lots of people - very reasonably, I'd say - would have a very strong emotional response.)

Comment: @Stiv a minor nitpick: the Nazi swastika is the mirror image. This one is a Buddist symbol.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Don't worry, I'm aware :) But at a glance not everyone will switch on to that and it will still bring about a reaction (even though wrongly) that might produce a downvote...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer should be

> [image]

Here is an image to simplify the problem:

> [image] 
>  A 3x3 dot grid, where each dot in the  grid represents a **pivot.**

And here is an image illustrating the steps to reach the solution (for row 1 and row 3):

> [image] 
>  Each circled color works as a pivot. The axis belonging to the outer pivots (eight in total) rotates clockwise around that pivot until it reaches the next pivot. The central pivot, which have two axes, rotates anti clockwise until they reaches the next pivot.

Comment: Although you haven't shown it explicitly, this does also work for the middle row - the corner ones all start off pointing to the centre.

Comment: @Stiv Yeah I skipped row 2 (lazy). I just chose row 1 as an example to show that it works for row 3 too.

Comment: Note that there is a progression vertically as well, although I think it's a little more complex.  But each colour follows the same progression from row 1 to row 2 and row 2 to row 3, in each column. (Some stay fixed throughout (corners), some rotate 2 steps counterclockwise each time (edge midpoints), and the long central blue one rotates a single step clockwise.)

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for answering. You explained it well. 

Comment: @JamesKojirou Thanks. Looking forward for the other one :)